# Iphone tabBarController.moreNavigationController options

Tags: iphone

I have multiple navigationcontrollers on the More Section of the tabBarcontroller,> 4.  When I clicked on one of the navigationcontrollers on the More Section,(table view) and then leave , and come back, it always come back to that specific controller view on the More Section.

I want to go back to the Table list view on More Section. I don't want to go back to a specific controller view on the More Section.  I want the general table view.

Answer (score 6):

Set your `UITabBarController`'s delegate appropriately, and implement this `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
    shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
    [nvc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    return YES;
}
```

This ensures that all of your navigation controllers (i.e. every tab) will be at their root when the tab is selected.

To do this only for the More tab, you can compare `viewController` to `tabBarController.moreNavigationController` and do the `popToRootViewController:` call selectively for that case.

Answer (score 1):

In your tabBar delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

you could get your selectedViewcontroller, and tell it to pop it's navigation controller stack.

```
 [[tabBarController selectedViewController].navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```